# JavaFX onDragOver event unable to be reached

Tags: javafx

I am unable to reach any event besides onDragDetected and onDragDone. I am unsure why.

I am using Text objects and attempting to drag from one Text object to the other

After running the program, I can only print the following:

OnDragDetected

OnDragDone

OnDragDetected

My minimal reproducible example is as follows:

```
    
public class Main extends Application {
    @Override public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle("Hello Drag And Drop");

        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 200);
        scene.setFill(Color.LIGHTGREEN);

        final Text source = new Text(50, 100, "DRAG ME");
        source.setScaleX(2.0);
        source.setScaleY(2.0);

        final Text target = new Text(250, 100, "DROP HERE");
        target.setScaleX(2.0);
        target.setScaleY(2.0);

        source.setOnDragDetected(new EventHandler <MouseEvent>() {
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                /* drag was detected, start drag-and-drop gesture*/
                System.out.println("onDragDetected");

                /* allow any transfer mode */
                Dragboard db = source.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.ANY);

                /* put a string on dragboard */
                ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
                content.putString(source.getText());
                db.setContent(content);

                event.consume();
            }
        });

        target.setOnDragOver(new EventHandler <DragEvent>() {
            public void handle(DragEvent event) {
                /* data is dragged over the target */
                event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.ANY);
                System.out.println("onDragOver");

                event.consume();
            }
        });

        target.setOnDragEntered(new EventHandler <DragEvent>() {
            public void handle(DragEvent event) {
                System.out.println("onDragEntered");
                event.consume();
            }
        });

        target.setOnDragExited(new EventHandler <DragEvent>() {
            public void handle(DragEvent event) {
                System.out.println("onDragExited");

                event.consume();
            }
        });

        target.setOnDragDropped(new EventHandler <DragEvent>() {
            public void handle(DragEvent event) {
                System.out.println("onDragDropped");

                event.consume();
            }
        });

        source.setOnDragDone(new EventHandler <DragEvent>() {
            public void handle(DragEvent event) {
                System.out.println("onDragDone");


                event.consume();
            }
        });

        root.getChildren().add(source);
        root.getChildren().add(target);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you create a [mre]? Something we can copy, paste, and run as-is

Comment: I updated the posted code to reveal the entire example @James_D

Comment: It works as expected for me... `onDragDetected onDragEntered onDragOver (xN) onDragDropped onDragExited onDragDone`

Comment: Can I ask what version of JavaFX and Java you are using? I am using JavaFX 12 and Java 11.

Comment: JavaFX v 14 and JDK 11

Comment: Wow. What a fix! I updated my JavaFX from 12 to 15 and now it's working great. That thought should've crossed my mind earlier, thank you for your help!